# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on blinking cursor from ctrtl+alt+f3, loading spinner on ctrl+alt+f1

Tags: ubuntu, boot

My system got into a bad state after installing packages trying to get a Rust game engine (bevy) working.

I ended up reinstalling lightdm which had gotten uninstalled. This was from the TTY login.

Now, when I boot I don't get the TTY. I see loading screen. Ctrl+Alt+f3 shows a blinking cursor - no shell.

I tried holding shift at start, nothing. Is there a way to load some kind of safe mode / GRUB settings?

Comment: Try starting in Recovery Mode:    https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode